# ModuleNotFoundError when using setup.cfg and version accessed with attr

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py

I have a Python package with the following structure:

```
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── myproject
        ├── base.py
        ├── __init__.py
        └── version.py
```

In `setup.cfg`, the version is defined with `attr`:

```
[metadata]
name = myproject
version = attr: myproject.version.__version__
```

With `version.py` being simply:

```py
__version__ = "1.2.3"
```

The package have dependencies listed in `setup.cfg`. On the other hand, the package's top level `__init__.py` imports some objects of the package:

```py
from myproject.base import Stuff

__all__ = ["Stuff"]
```

And, obviously, `base.py` imports some objects from the dependencies.

The problem is now that if I try to use `python setup.py` when the dependencies are not installed, I have a `ModuleNotFoundError`/`ImportError`, since `__init__.py` imports objects importing these dependencies (this is very to case 6 in [the Python documentation on managing version file](https://packaging.python.org/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/)):

```
python setup.py --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
<snip>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dependency_module'
```

which makes installation of the dependencies impossible. So what should be the best strategy to target the version file?

So far, I have tried this weird exception handling approach on `__init__.py`:

```py
try:
    from myproject.base import Stuff
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Is there a better way? Or another approach?

Comment: What is your version of setuptools? It should be at least `39.2.0` for `version = attr: myproject.version.__version__` to work.

Comment: Version is above 40.0.0.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1724 . I am really surprised, from my point of view it kind of ruins the point of having the `version = attr: myproject.version.__version__` feature in the first place. I am a bit confused...

Comment: Yes, I agree completely! The error is absolutely logic, but pretty inevitable if you use `attr:`.

Comment: It looks like the situation with `attr:` has improved in the mean time: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/1753 -- Seems like it has been released in [_v46.4.0_ on _16 May 2020_](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v46-4-0)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you are running into the issue filed here: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1724

You'd be better off writing your version number in a `VERSION.txt`, read it from `setup.cfg` with `version = file: VERSION.txt`, and load it from your `__init__.py` with `import importlib_metadata; __version__ = importlib_metadata.version('myproject')`.

---

**Update**

The package [`importlib_metadata` is on PyPI for current Python versions](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/) and starting with [*Python 3.8* in the standard library as `importlib.metadata`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/importlib.metadata.html).

Now with all that said, the need for having the version string in a separate file could be reconsidered. Since there is a straightforward way to read the version string from within the code, the purpose of `version.py` or `VERSION.txt` might be lost.

Alternatively I tend to make my setup scripts [read the version string from the *changelog*](https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/project_version.html) instead.

---

***Update*** *3 November 2020*:

It looks like the situation with `attr:` has improved in the mean time, thanks to this [change](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/1753). If possible, using `attr:` does not actually import the code and thus the `ModuleNotFoundError` originally reported in the question should not happen anymore. It has been released in [*v46.4.0* on *16 May 2020*](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v46-4-0).

Comment: This solved the problem pretty elegantly. As a side note, `importlib_metadata` is a third party package you have to install. It will be part of the standard library as `importlib.metadata` starting Python 3.8.

Comment: True. I updated the answer with this info and a bit more.

Comment: Your last comment about eventually storing the version number in `setup.cfg` instead of a dedicated file is very true as well.