# version = attr: in setup.cfg, ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, setuptools

In my Python project with the directory layout

```
.
├── justfile
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
└── src
    └── foobar
        ├── __about__.py
        ├── __init__.py
        └── main.py
```

`__about__.py` reads

```py
__version__ = "1.0.0"
```

I would like to use this version info in `setup.cfg`. I tried

```
[metadata]
name = foobar
version = attr: foobar.__about__.__version__

[options]
package_dir =
    =src
packages = find:
install_requires =
    rich
python_requires = >=3.6

[options.packages.find]
where=src
```

but this still tries to import foobar, resulting in `ModuleNotFoundError`s from foobars dependencies when trying to evaluate the version string.

The `__init__.py` reads

```
from .main import solve
from .__about__ import __version__
```

I had been under the impression that after [this PR](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/1753) has been merged, just the AST of the `attr` was evaluated. (See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58220353/353337).)

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Please show the rest of your `setup.cfg`, and the relevant file/directory tree layout?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError when using setup.cfg and version accessed with attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58202909/modulenotfounderror-when-using-setup-cfg-and-version-accessed-with-attr)

Comment: hi nico. it is not good practice to fundamentally edit your question so that it basically asks something different after it has already has answers. the answer by AKX now doesn't make sense and as someone else coming here after the fact, I was very confused. Please consider rolling back the parts that outdated his answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. In `__init__.py`, the `__version__` must be imported *before* all external dependencies. This

```py
from .__about__ import __version__
from .main import solve
```

works.

Comment: This... shouldn't matter since your example shows importing the attribute from `__about__.py` (and I can verify that with an empty `__init__.py`, `attr:foobar.__about__.__version__` works just fine).

Comment: Ah, okay, right: I slapped a `traceback.print_stack()` in `__about__.py` – turns out that `importlib.util.find_spec` ends up importing the package...

Comment: Not sure at all why I'm getting the downvotes, but this is the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure either. Both answers are part of the solution...

Answer (score 2):

`src` is not part of the package import path (you wouldn't do `import src.foobar` with your installed package), it's just a directory.

Try

```
version = attr:foobar.__about__.__version__
```

instead (assuming you've [set up the `src/` layout in setup.cfg](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#using-a-src-layout)).

Comment: Same result unfortunately.